# Query for all themes?

Tags: themes, multisite

I am running Wordpress 3.1.3 Multisite and would like to find out all of the currently-activated themes.  I know there is a feature in the admin to see plugins per-blog, but I have not been able to see a similar feature for themes.

Answer (score 1):

I just found it...under the "wp__options" table, it is "template".